# Чем плохо возникновение ошибок в работе с БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня есть база данных, в которой время от времени меняются столбцы(добавляются, удаляются). Php-скрипт занимается тем, что делает команды `UPDATE`. Так вот, мне по сути нужно так: если столбец и запись есть, то они обновляются, если же их нет, то не происходит ничего.

Собственно вопрос: можно ли обращаться к БД без проверок, чтобы если столбца нет, то происходила бы ошибка и на нее никак не реагировать? Или же нужно делать проверки? Тогда ошибок не будет, но будут затраты по производительности. Как правильнее?

Comment: В типичных юзкейсах РСУБД столбцы полагаются заранее известными, а приложение оперирует существованием разве что записей. У вас плохо нормализованы данные?

Comment: В случае ошибки, как минимум, нужно убедится что это именно та ошибка которую вы ожидали (отсутсвие столбца, а не отсутсвие тиблицы, не ошибки транзакции, не  restrict на связанном поле).

Comment: Как часто вы меняете колонки в таблицах и для чего?

Comment: @Arnial частота изменений может быть различна. Сколько пожелает пользователь, столько и меняю...

Comment: @D-side ситуация такая: у меня php-демон раз в 5 минут получает данные с сайтов, проверяет их и заносит в базу если они подходят под условие. Столбцы в базе данных - это сайты. Пользователь может в любой момент добавить или удалить сайт. Хотя демон обходит только те сайты, что есть в БД, я рассматриваю случай, когда пользователь удалил сайт в момент, когда демон в середине выполнения - именно тогда мы можем обратится к несуществующему столбцу.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос довольно странный. Как сказал D-side в нормальной ситуации столбцы редко меняются.

*Можно ли обращаться к БД без проверок* (иммеются в виду предпроверки)

Да, можно и даже желательно. Проверка того что столбец существует не даёт гарантий что он будет существовать во время запроса на обновление (или что соединение с базой не отвалится сразу после проверки).

Но, проверять произошла ли ошибка в запросе нужно всегда (ответ сервера). Ошибки в запросах могут происходить по множеству разных причин, от ошибки  в самом запросе (sql синтаксис, несуществующее поле ...)  до отказа диска или нехватки места ([см. коды ошибок](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html)). Если вы знаете что в данном запросе иногда может происходить ошибка и это нормально, то вы должны проверить что запрос провалился именно из-за *запланированной* ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще я думаю нужно отталкиваться не от скрипта а от перечня колонок в таблице. Ну к пример. Анализируем таблицу и уже потом формируем нам нужный скрипт в зависимости от условий.